# Datasheet of camera autofocus driver IC

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, pinout, connecting

I have a camera lens with auto focus. I opened it and found a tiny (2x1 mm) IC. A search on Google for "auto focus IC" showed it has 6 pins (GND, Vcc, SDA, SCL, and 2 outputs for the voice coil), and I2C communication.

The number on the IC is AKM 30 5F 45. If I don't have the datasheet, how can I determinate what Vcc, ground, and the data lines on the PCB are? It has exposed a four pin pad. It is from a S4 GT-i9500 back camera/rear camera.

IC number:

[image]

Four pin pad

[image]

Voice coil IC and capacitor:

[image]

Comment: Different part numbers. May offer some clues|| https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv201.pdf?ts=1708668685394&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

and https://nz.mouser.com/new/rohm-semiconductor/rohm-bi-directional-vcm-drivers/

Comment: AKM could mean the manufacturer is [Asahi Kasei Microdevices (AKM)](https://www.akm.com), I can't find any other AKM IC with a similar marking style though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to the traces somewhere with a scope, it will be pretty obvious what the power pins are, SCL and SDA. If you scope the two together, SCL will change state more often and always when SDA does not.